# Where do people put licence information in Maven projects?

Tags: maven, licensing, pom.xml

What are the usual places where people put information about projects' licenses beside POM's license tag?  Also I'm interested in unusual ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen license info in `/src/main/resources`, `/src/main/etc`, under `META-INF`, you name it. I'm not sure there's a canonical location.

Answer (score 2):

Per the [Maven Standard Directory Layout](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html), at the root of the project, is a LICENSE.TXT describing the license of that project.